# Is it possible to set EXTR_SKIP as the default behavior for PHP's extract()?

Tags: php, security, extract

I have a legacy app which makes heavy use of the [extract()](http://php.net/extract) function.  It's good security practice to use the EXTR_SKIP flag (e.g. `extract($array_of_stuff, EXTR_SKIP)`) when using this on untrusted data, to avoid malicious users overwriting existing variables.  Naturally my legacy app does no such thing.

So my question is, is there any way I can set EXTR_SKIP as the default behavior for extract()?  I'm still going through and specify it manually, but if I can set that globally I'd prefer to do so now to improve the app's security while I'm slogging through.

Comment: Not as far as I know (unless employing runkit, which isnt a good idea on production). Can't you just define a new function and use a `find -iname '*.php' -exec sed --in-place=backup.php s/\bextract\(/newfunc\(/g {} \;`?

Comment: @DaveRandom: with PHP>=5.3, do you mean to use namespaces? Tricky, because extract goes to the current scope, not the global scope.. So unless everything is global it does not work.

Comment: Yes, I'm on PHP 5.3.2.  I've more or less finished the process now -- I found everything with a grep and did the alterations.  But I'd still like to know if there's a way to override the default extract behavior, so I'll leave the question open.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say the answer is no.  A simple wrapper function is best so *grep* etc is the way to go on this one.  Even if you changed the default behavior that's a bad idea if you're running any third party libs that use [extract](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php) and expect the normal default behavior.  If you're not running third party libs, fair enough, but there's still no way to do it short of a hack afaik.